# Different results produced by linearRegression.score and svm.svc(kernel = linear)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation

I am very new to machine learning.

I have one dataset and I want to apply test-train split and cross validation for linear regression on it.

I have tried to split the dataset using train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3), and I performed both

```
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)
reg.score(X_test,y_test)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel = 'linear').fit(X_train,y_train)
clf.score(X_test,y_test)
```

the reg.score gives an output of 0.98, but the clf.score only gives a very low, close to 0 output. Why are these result different?

I also attempted

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, random_state=42)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=2)
```

It also gives very small numbers, and saw this warning

```
UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than n_splits=2.
  % (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)
```

I have tried different cv but cv>5 gives an error "n_splits=5 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class." Note that the dataset I am using is not a binary or a simple multiclass. It's more like a monthly sales data than a categorizing one. I think that is probably why it is causing the warning. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up regression (for continuous valued targets) and classification here.
The [linear regression model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) expects a continuous valued target and it's score is the coefficient of determination.
The [support vector classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) is a classification method and it's score is classification accuracy.

You state that your target is not categorical so I suppose you would want to go with [support vector regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) instead of SVC.

Since you say to be new to machine learning maybe also have a look at [this tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#introduction).

Comment: Thanks! That's a great suggestion, however after I attempted it i still got different score -- this time svm.svr.score is like -500ish, is that abnormal or I just need to look at something else?

Comment: A negative R2 score is possible (as noted in [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.score)), however -500 would mean that your models predictions are way off. Best recheck your code if there are any gross mistakes. Or maybe there have been warnings regarding convergence? Also have a look at the score for the training set. If it is equally bad something went wrong during training.